# Bootstrap ScrollSpy from javascript call not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm building a bootstrap based website, at the moment I have a problem.
If I call from `data-attributes`:

```
<body  data-target=".navbar" data-spy="scroll"  data-offset="200">
```

Scrollspy does work.

But if I use javascript

```
$('.navbar').scrollspy({offset:200});
```

this does not work!

I also already try to put attributes on the fly:

```
$("body").data("target", ".navbar");
$("body").data("spy", "scroll");
$("body").data("offset", "200");
```

no result so far.

i think there's something missing with the javascript calling. if $('.navbar') is the target, where can i set the spy object (body)?

Comment: are you calling `.scrollspy` on document ready?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this, see if this helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/Tgghc/

Using data attributes the important bits are including the data-spy details in the div you want to spy on:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
.....
```

Then in your CSS define what you want to happen to this div when it's affixed, eg:

```
#nav-wrapper.affix {
top: 0;
width: 100%
}
```

Since the affixed div will be removed from normal flow, sometimes you need to play a bit so the affix behaviour doesn't result in a jump of the main content.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When calling scrollspy via JavaScript, specify the body tag (or another element with a scrollbar) and pass in the target nav as an option.

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar' });
```

*I am not sure why the bootstrap documentation says $('#navbar').scrollspy(). It is very misleading.*